# Force Close in the android app

Tags: java, android, xml, forceclose

### Android Studio

hi guys.

I wanted to make a simple app for android which uses <<**OnCheckedChangeListener**>> for a check box in android studio. I looked at the questions which were like mine for example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495023/force-close-in-android-app), but I found no problem in my codes. These Are Mine. Thanks a lot in advance.

This Is My **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.gna.myapplication;
  
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public CheckBox chbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CH1);
    public TextView txt1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TXT1);

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener list=new       CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                txt1.setText("A New Era");
            else
                txt1.setText("MasterByte");

        }
    };
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(list);
    }
}
```

And The XML is:

activity_main.Xml,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/rl">

    <TextView android:text="MasterByte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="#F00FF0"
        android:id="@+id/TXT1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Here"
        android:id="@+id/CH1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TXT1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TXT1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TXT1"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

OKAY.
My problem is that the app won't start and it shows force close error.
I wanted to use exception classes and [try(),catch(),finally()] but I didn't know how . If you Know how to do That , I'm waiting :D
Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: The fact that you get a force close only tells us that your app crashed. The relevant info on why and where it crashed is vital to any kind of debugging unless we should resort to going through all your code just for the sake of it. Please check logcat for any exception stacktrace and supply it with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the initialization of

```
 public CheckBox chbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CH1);
 public TextView txt1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TXT1);
```

inside `onCreate` and after `setContentView`. You need a valid `Context` and something to look for before being able to actually find something

> My problem is that the app won't start and it shows force close
>   error.

you can't use [findViewById](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) before the `Activity` goes for its lifecycle.

Comment: Right. So this was an easy find. You can't expect to find a view before you've inflated any layout. But, OP, please take lesson from this to supply proper logs with questions, as opposed to just saying "I get a force close, why?"

Comment: the only problem of what ?